# Filestack - NoCrop: Add Whitespace to image sides to upload without cropping and keeping square

Tags: html, api, file, file-upload

How can I upload an image with Filestack and automaticly add whitespace to image sides for keep the image square without crop the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMTt0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the border options after uploading.
They are listed here:
https://www.filestack.com/docs/image-transformations/borders-and-effects